# Does a method's return value occupy memory if not put into a variable (in .NET 6)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have these two C# 10 (.NET 6) methods:

```
public List<User> ReadAllFromCacheOrDb()
{
    // the logic inside this repository will implement the cache
    return _userRepository.ReadAllFromCacheOrDb();
}

private void SetCache()
{
    ReadAllFromCacheOrDb();
}
```

I was going to use `SetCache()` method whenever I wanted to update the cache like this:

```
public Task<User> Create(IdentityUser<long> entity)
{
    var result = _userRepository.Create(entity);
    SetCache();
    return result;
}

public User Update(IdentityUser<long> entity)
{
    var result = _userRepository.Update(entity);
    SetCache();
    return result;
}
```

Now I was wondering if the `SetCache()` method will occupy more memory than usual because of not putting the return value of `ReadAllFromCacheOrDb()` into any variable.

Will the garbage collector quickly dispose of things like this?

Comment: *returning* a value which already exists is pretty cheap (normally just a register, which would be unused otherwise). However *creating* that value might be expensive, and a waste if noone's going to use it. If `userRepository.ReadAllFromCacheOrDb()` creates a new `List<User>` every time it's called, then calling `SetCache` will end up creating a new pointless `List<User>` each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now I was wondering if the SetCache() method will occupy more memory than usual because of not putting the return value of ReadAllFromCacheOrDb() into any variable.

It does not really matter if you have a variable or not. The compiler will likely rewrite the method into [static single assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) form, will optimize register and stack space usage.

However, the returned list itself will still be allocated on the heap, and will remain there until it is freed by the GC. This will likely not be a problem unless your list is huge, but it might help a little if you could avoid creating the list in the first place.

In general, use a memory and/or performance profiler if you are concerned about things like this. These will tell you if there is a problem, and where it is. It is very common for developers to worry about the wrong things, and spend a bunch of time optimizing things that have a minimal performance impact, while missing problems that do have a large impact.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector quickly disposes of object's that are only used very briefly. It is optimized for that scenario. Also it has only minimal bookkeeping for those objects, so the cost of allocating and collecting is very low.

If the List that is created by **ReadAllFromCacheOrDb()** falls in that category is a different matter.
If it is small, yes. It probably took little time to create it and it will fit in the quick-to-collect memory of the garbage collector.

If the list is longer it might not fit, or to much time is spend and memory consumed inside **ReadAllFromCacheOrDb()** to trigger the garbage collector to look at the situation. It will do some cleanup, but keep the list and it associated objects. They will no longer live in the quick-to-collect memory and become expensive.

How expensive? Only measuring can tell. If this concerns only several thousands of objects and updates are not frequent I would not worry about it.